# Self Study Real Analysis from this series of books by Jacob & Evans?

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning, book-recommendation

Once again a question about self-studying real analysis by an amateur graces these forums, but I am fairly certain these authors have not been mentioned here so far and I would appreciate your thoughts.

I am currently torn between the following two paths for learning analysis:

**[More Mainstream books]**

- Introduction to Real Analysis (by Robert Bartle)
- Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra and Differential Forms: A Unified Approach (by Hubbard&Hubbard)

Or

**[The series of books by Jacob & Evans]**

- https://www.amazon.co.uk/Course-Analysis-Introductory-Calculus-Functions/dp/9814689092/ref=pd_sbs_14_3?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=9814689092&pd_rd_r=5fc48019-fac3-11e8-a264-19c21d2ec568&pd_rd_w=TPZUc&pd_rd_wg=1xZ4X&pf_rd_p=18edf98b-139a-41ee-bb40-d725dd59d1d3&pf_rd_r=095364ZX5K2QJ1H2SZS0&psc=1&refRID=095364ZX5K2QJ1H2SZS0
- https://www.amazon.co.uk/Course-Analysis-Differentiation-Integration-Functions/dp/9813140968/ref=pd_sbs_14_1?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=9813140968&pd_rd_r=e6a7cab3-fac4-11e8-ad45-bf011ec9f832&pd_rd_w=soq8b&pd_rd_wg=O20Kc&pf_rd_p=18edf98b-139a-41ee-bb40-d725dd59d1d3&pf_rd_r=KFM070QJCAHCV541V3PQ&psc=1&refRID=KFM070QJCAHCV541V3PQ

The latter books by **Jacob & Evans** are the first two in a series of seven containing **completely solved exercises**. Reviews and previews are hard to come by, I only managed to find these

**Review:**

- Volume 1 :
  https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/a-course-in-analysis-volume-i-introductory-calculus-analysis-of-functions-of-one-real-variable
- Volume 2 :
  https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/a-course-in-analysis-volume-ii-differentiation-and-integration-of-functions-of-several-variables

**Preview:**

- Volume 1:
  https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Wzg8DQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false
- Volume 2:
  https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8JpIDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Does anyone have any experience with these books? If not, what do you think based on the previews/reviews? Or should I just stick to the conventional Bartle/Hubbard path? Or any other suggestions for someone who has self-studied the following books so far :

Calculus (Stewart),Vector Calculus (Colley, skipped many proofs)
Discrete mathematics (by Epp),Complex Analysis (Zill & Shanahan, did most proofs)

There were some other ones as well...but too long ago now

Thanks.

**P.S.**
I found some additional chapter previews here:
https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/9625#t=suppl

Comment: I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but when learning introductory analysis I used Abbott's Understanding Analysis, and found it to be paced at a level just slow enough for me. If you're just beginning I recommend checking that out. If you're more advanced then rudin's book is great too.

Comment: Thank you for a comment.I was afraid nobody was going to respond.I have looked into Abbott aswell,it seems a little more discursive than i think would like at this point.I'll probably stick with Bartle after all and go from there.Nontheless, i was curious about the Jacob/Evans volumes aswell when i stumbled upon them.

Comment: I'd say just start on whichever one you like. Starting with a good book isn't as important as actually doing it. If you feel like you can't follow or if it is too easy for you, then switch.